# How to connect mysql database with android

Tags: android

I'm developing an application in android. I use an sqlite3 database. But I need to implement in mysql database using wamp server.

Comment: Do you want to connect to an external database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use PHP scripts which handle all the database things on your WAMP.
This script will react as a bridge between your MySql and Android.

After this, make network requests to this script from your Android device and get data returned by the database.

You must understand that MySql isn't available to Android devices locally, thus you can't access it the way you access sqlite on a device. To get this, you'll have to implement something like a webservice.