# Connect android app to active mysql database

Tags: android, mysql

So, I am extremely new to android programming, and I was just wondering, if i wanted to create a native app that could connect to my current database, so that users will still have their profiles and everything. what do i do?

I have tried loads of resources, but found nothing.
Maybe there is a way to connect sqllite, and mysql? i have absolutely no idea.
Please help

Comment: Wow, look at all those questions under **Related** to the right... did that list not appear whilst you were typing your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect mysql database with android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323294/how-to-connect-mysql-database-with-android)

Comment: No like an idiot, i just decided to ask a question without going through similar questions first

Answer (score 1):

To connect to sqlite database you need to use the [sqliteopenhelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) class in android.

You cannot have a MySql database for local storage. But you can connect to a remote database but posting data to a remote URL. A simple php script at that URL can query or update the MySQL database and give a response in JSON format which can be parsed easily in android. This [tutorial](http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/) is really helpful for that.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no direct approach to do that (if you mean that you want to connect **`MySQL`** website database to **`SQLite`** mobile database) but you might want to search and consider using web services in order to access your mysql database like [ksoap2](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net) or any other type of web service.

another approach is to use http as shown in this [example](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database).

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Android work great with sqllite. Here is a small docu with sample: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db